# Table load VBA vs Built in function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a rather odd thing happening to me when I import a table into access.

I have tried doing this in three ways...

Firstly, I import the table (from a text file) using the built in functionality and having defined (and saved) the Import Specification everything works tickety-boo.

Next I re-run the upload by creating a macro but with reference to the Import Specification file that I saved above.

The problem is, some of the Import Specifications are not holding when I do it this way, in particular, I have requested that one field has indexing (No Duplicates), however when it loads with the macro it sets the fields indexing back to the default position back to "No"

I also tried to load the table using VBA (with reference to the same Import Specification File), but encounter the same problem.

Does anyone know how to maintain the integrity of the indexing when doing automated loads based of spec files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest way to control upload(if you have to change upload scenario dynamically) is to use custom VBA code to create and fill table with date from the source. The reason for that, in my opinion, the specifications and export/import system in Access is working, but weak and have pretty low level tools to use it via VBA, because it was mainly created for hand import/export with Access interface.

PS by custom VBA code, i mean the code that absolutely avoid built-in import features. Again this only make sense if your import/export scenario is dynamic and need to make choices in a process. If it's static and can be created using standard features, then just do it by hand with a step by step wizard and then call it with your VBA code without any changes.